# Кастомная настройка шрифта Android

Tags: android, textview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно в Андроиде сделать текст, как вот на картинке? Т.е чтобы рубли были "большие", а копейки были выше и маленькие

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавить html-тэги в ресурсы string:

```
<string name="price"><big>1</big><sup><small>99</small></sup></string>
```

- `<big>` делает текст больше стандартного.
- `<small>` делает текст меньше стандартного.
- `<sup>` приподнимает над строкой.

[image: пример]

PS. В просмотре макета форматирование не будет видно (не знаю почему), но в работе приложения отображется как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать разделить цену на 2 `TextView` и задать им стили. Например так:

```
<style name="Rub">
    <item name="android:textSize">18pt</item>
</style> 
<style name="Kop">
    <item name="android:textSize">6pt</item>
    <item<name="android:paddingBottom">20dp</item>
</style>    
<!-- Размеры шрифта и отступов, если, что подгоните. -->
```

Также, если мне память не изменяет, `TextView` понимает простую HTML разметку.